# cannot import name 'mss' from partially initialized module 'mss' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, importerror, python-mss

mss library bug, I was trying most simple [Example Program](https://pypi.org/project/mss/).
I have reinstall that library but still same error.

```
from mss import mss

with mss() as sct:
    sct.shot()
```

And that's what I got.

Comment: Is your own file called `mss.py`?

Comment: @wim hmm yes, I forgot I named it my file same as the library